# Why does integrate.quad(lambda x: x*exp(-x**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi), 0.0, 100000) give 0?

Tags: numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

This function is positive from 0 to inf, why give larger than 1000 will yield to 0, not reasonable.

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
from math import *

integrate.quad(lambda x: x*exp(-x**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi), 0.0, 1000)
Out[52]: 
(0.3989422804014328, 1.6471510195390376e-11)
integrate.quad(lambda x: x*exp(-x**2/2)/sqrt(2*pi), 0.0, 100000)
Out[54]: 
(0.0, 0.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For x larger than approx. 39, `exp(-x**2/2)` gives 0.0.  When the upper limit of integration is 100000, the fraction of the interval of integration where the function is nonzero is so small that the `quad` algorithm never sees it.  As far as `quad` is concerned, the function is identically 0.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Fix it in general, for an arbitrary function?  I don't know of a method.  You have to know a little about the behavior of your function to use `quad` (or any numerical integration algorithm) effectively.  If you want to fix it for this particular function, you could simply use the analytical expression for the integral instead of using `quad`.